# jQuery replace comma with dot doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to append the code from another post which works perfectly on fiddle on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/WfpEu/51/

The code replaces comma "," as soon as the user types it and turns it to dot "."

```
$.fn.ForceNumericOnly = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode==188 || e.keyCode==110 || e.keyCode==108){
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');
                }
                    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                    return (key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || key == 110 || key == 188 || key == 190 || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105));                
            });
        });
};
$(".item").ForceNumericOnly();
```

I have tried to append it to my code here http://jsfiddle.net/p2Hbm/104/ and it doesn't work as it should and i don't know what is wrong. I can't write letters in input fields which is good but also i can't write comma "," it doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `item`class to your input fields.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Hbm/106/

Comment: happens to the best of us :)